# Doctrine Cli on Windows

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, command-line-interface

I am having some trouble configuring doctrine orm on windows 8, php 5.4. I have installed Doctrine using Composer.

I have followed the docs to the letter but when I run any commands, `php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create` for example, my command line just outputs

```
SRC_DIR="`pwd`"
cd "`dirname "$0"`"
cd "../doctrine/orm/bin"
BIN_TARGET="`pwd`/doctrine"
cd "$SRC_DIR"
"$BIN_TARGET" "$@"
```

I have also tried php `vendor/bin/doctrine.php` .... but it just prints out the above.

I have followed Doctrine's guide to the letter. Has anyone seen this before and if so, can you suggest anything?

Comment: This is an UNIX script - you need a `bash` emulator for Windows in order to run that.

Comment: @moonwave99 and Ocramius - Thanks for your responses, I really appreciate your help. I tried this with git bash and console2 but it still just prints out the file contents. I've never really seen anything like this before. I will keep trying to work it out!

Comment: @mikedhart if you are able to reproduce it, consider opening a ticket at http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC
Eventually, delete the `doctrine.bat` command and just use the `doctrine.php` as last resort.

Comment: i am also facing same problem .
did not found any solution till now.
please help?

Comment: if you take a look at vendor/bin there's another file called "doctrine.php.bat" - I managed to run queries using it instead of simply "doctrine" (win7, wamp, php 5.3, php is added to the PATH)

Answer (score 23):

i found a solution

there are also a bin folder   in  vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/ you can use this one  like this

> php   vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create

make sure you have  root folder and  a cli-config.php file is present in root folder.

below is location where i found a solution

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/doctrine-user/_ph183Kh-5o/_P_coljB-dcJ

this is working fine  for me .

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem. The following solution worked for me:

```
"vendor/bin/doctrine.bat" orm:schema-tool:create
```

So, basically you:

- use the ".bat" file provided by Doctrine and
- enclose the call to that ".bat" file in quotes.

### My Environment

Windows 7 Professional (x64)
PHP 5.5.12
Doctrine ORM 2.4.4

Comment: Basicly you dont need quotes nor .bat at the end.

Comment: @ArekKostrzeba I am not sure about that. When I run `vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create` the console responds with the following error message: _'vendor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file_. On the other hand, you are absolutely right about the _.bat_ extension not being necessary.

Comment: I had the same problem and just figured it out. Add forward slashes \ and it works. vendor\bin\doctrine. I guess I can say thanks for help because this thread kind off helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 6):

Do not write "php..." (it will write the file content)

Just "vendor\bin\doctrine orm:schema-tool:create" do the job (from the project root eg. c:\php\theProject).

Next, you will need a "cli-config.php" in the project root...

Comment: Thanks, this answer did the job for me and I believe it to be the correct answer. Using a different binary as suggested in another answer seems quite risky.

Answer (score 3):

For Window version use backward slash **"\"**

`vendor\bin\doctrine orm:schema-tool:create`

not forward slash **"/"**

`vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create`

Answer (score 2):

You can either install something like [git bash](http://msysgit.github.com/) or simply use the PHP version of the script:

```
php vendor\bin\doctrine.php orm:info
```

Obviously, the `php` binary directory should be in your `PATH` environment variable, otherwise, it's something like:

```
C:\path\to\php.exe vendor\bin\doctrine.php orm:info
```

Comment: +1 because I couldn't do it without including the full path to php.exe For wamp users, it's C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\php.exe But you'd need to change the version number of course :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy doctrine.bat (located at vendor/bin/doctrine.bat) to your project root directory
2. Create a `bootstrap.php` file in any path inside your project root directory with the following content:

   ```
   use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
   use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

   $paths = array("../model");
   $isDevMode = false;
   $dbParams = array(
       'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
       'host' => 'localhost',
       'user'     => 'root',
       'password' => '',
       'dbname'   => 'angular_php',
   );

   $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
   $entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
   ```
3. Create a `cli-config.php` file in your project root directory with the following content:

   ```
   <?php

   use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;

   // replace with file to your own project bootstrap
   require_once 'path/to/file/bootstrap.php';

   return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
   ```
4. Execute from a command line window (CMD):

   ```
   c:\path\to\project\root\directory>doctrine --help
   ```
5. It's done!

Answer (score 0):

I found it wasnt returning anything from the doctrine.php.bat. Turns out it was a PHP error in my cli-config.php file

Answer (score 0):

Using Cygwin on Windows with doctrine installed via composer, was having the same problem

resolved by:

vendor/bin/doctrine.bat orm:convert-mapping

if you are still having issues you can run the cli script using php to get the console tools running:

for example

php cli-config.php orm:schema-tool:create

Answer (score 0):

All the answers on this question are either outdated or outright incorrect. In my case, I observed, after installing the the library, the "\vendor\doctrine\orm\" folder was completely empty. The docs ask you to run vendor/bin/doctrine, which in turn attempts to call "vendor\doctrine\orm\bin\doctrine[.php]" (The php file extension is optional). After discovering this, I downloaded the library from the git repository and replaced the composer-installed version.

```
php vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine
```

then works fine.

Also, beware of the common misconception that the cli-config.php file must exist in the root of your project. It's fine to leave it in your config folder